# How to decrypt eCryptfs files that were recovered using photorec from a damaged partition

Tags: linux, ecryptfs

I used [photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) -- to a reasonable degree of success -- to recover files from a damage home partition where users' homes were encrypted using ecryptfs on Ubuntu.

The salvaged files are now named similar to `f5345000.eCryptfs`. I'm assuming not all files from the original set were recovered. Moreover, the directory structure no longer exists.

eCryptfs had filename encryption enabled, which is the default for Ubuntu.

Assuming I have the eCryptFS passphrase. Is it possible to decrypt those files? How can it be done?

Comment: *Is it possible to decrypt those files?* Most likely not but I'm not an expert so you should wait for answers or other comments.

Answer (score 1):

eCryptfs usually needs a `wrapped-passphrase` file that stores the actual encryption key ("mount passphrase"), or you need the mount passphrase itself.

If you have one of those, you can try `ecryptfs-recover-private` to "find and mount any encrypted private directories". Since filenames were encrypted I don't think they could be recovered, their names were encrypted in the filenames, and `photorec` doesn't usually recover filenames (making just finding the `wrapped-passphrase` file difficult too) - I'm assuming `testdisk` didn't have any luck?

`ecryptfs-recover-private` needs the files in specific directories:

- encrypted files in `.Private`
- `wrapped-passphrase` in `$d/../.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase` (where $d is `.Private`, or a named directory)

Unless you tell it which directory to decrypt (doesn't have to be specifically named `.Private`). [My other answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/850793/ecryptfs-encrypted-home-explanation/850814#850814) has more info on eCryptfs, including the general layout.

`ecryptfs-recover-private` is just a shell script, so if you have difficulties you could try stepping through it manually if you wanted. In a terminal to quickly see it just use

```
less `which ecryptfs-recover-private`
```

I don't think eCryptfs requires every original file for successful decryption (otherwise deleting a single file would become a problem), but some of the recovered files might be truncated or have some bad data too, so it's definitely not guaranteed to work.

And if there were multiple users' encrypted files, they would have different mount passphrases too, but `photorec` probably recovered all the files in one big group. That means trying to decrypt all the files with each different mount passphrase, one at a time, and seeing if anything works. Backups are definitely preferred!